# How to get text/value that doesnt have HTML tags using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium

From the below HTML content,

```
<div id="header_cart"><a href="http://store.demoqa.com/products-page/checkout/" title="Checkout" class="cart_icon">
    <em class="count">
            1                                             
    </em> 
<em class="item">item</em> 
| 
<span class="icon" style="margin-top: 0px;">Cart</span>Checkout<span class="shadow"></span></a>
</div>
```

I want to read the value from first . I tried with the following command

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='header_cart']/a/em[1]")).getText());
```

I'm getting "item" instead of value "1"

Please help me how can I read the values that doesn't have the html tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.getAttribute("value");` instead​ of `.getText()`.

Comment: I'm getting NULL instead of value.

I have added two items to cart, I'm expecting 2 to be returned but getting NULL. Please advise

Comment: Try this xpath: "//div[@class='count']/a/em"

Comment: Or: "//em[@class='count']"

Comment: I got error as unable to locate element. 

I changed the code to "//em[@class='count']", it didn't throw any error but returned null

Comment: Did you try anything except xpath? Try to find by class name or CSS selector as suggested by Manmohan

Answer (score 0):

To extract the value `1` from the `<em>` tag you can use :

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='header_cart']//em[@class='count']")).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

### Update :

Probably, the driver is checking for the text too fast before the browser renders it. So try to induce `ExplicitWait` i.e. `WebDriverWait` as follows:

```
WebDriverWait cart_wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
cart_wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='header_cart']//em[@class='count']"), "1"));
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='header_cart']//em[@class='count']")).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
```

Comment: With this i'm able to see "0" instead of null but actual value should be a number i.e. the number of items in the cart.
store.demoqa.com is the site i'm testing.

Comment: Check out my updated Answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to use a CSS selector. I think your locator is finding the other `<em>` for some reason. I've added a wait below in case that is the issue. The text inside the `<em>` is full of extra spaces so you can add a trim() to clean up the text.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement itemCount = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#header_cart em.count")));
System.out.println(itemCount.getText().trim());
```